# Oracle apex how to put today's date as value placeholder?

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm creating a task time table as a learning project. And I want to put a today's date as a placeholder for one of the fields that can be changed if needed. How can I do that?

All I can find is 'Value placeholder' field, but I have no idea how to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, aren't you - actually - talking about item's **default value**? If so,

- navigate to item's properties
- scroll down to "Default" section
- choose type that is appropriate for what you want. For example, that might be

  - "Expression" which equals to `to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy')`, or
  - "Function body" which is then `return sysdate;`
  - etc.

---

If that's not it, could you post some more info? Screenshot of what you're doing is welcome.

Comment: I upvoted :) Just FYI, a "placeholder" is not the same as a default value. A placeholder also exists in apex as an item attribute and it is what is shown before the users enters anything in the field.

Comment: Aha! **That** "Value placeholder" property! OK, got it. I have no idea why I thought it was about item's default value ... probably because I use it frequently. Thank you for your comments, @Koen and Krumpirko.